# Resizing lots of images via PHP, keeping aspect and not using all my RAM?

Tags: php, memory-management, image-resizing, aspect-ratio

I have a problem that I thought was easily solved, but is turning out a little more difficult than anticipated.

I am working on a site which someone can upload images for a product, and it resizes them twice (500x500 and 150x150) on the fly. I am trying to keep the aspect ratio, for example if I had 600x500 image it would resize to 500x417 and 150x125.

I have found (lots) of code that does this, such as [this class](http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/blog/resizing-images-with-php/), however I always run into memory issues. I think  the class isn't unloading/destroying the temporary images after resizing.

I had the host upgrade my memory-limit to 64M from 32, however I run out of memory later. I'm stuck with PHP 5.2.13 as well, so no garbage collector for me.

My PHP is fairly new, so it's very alien to me how classes work, otherwise I would try adding the imagedestroy() function where required. I fiddled with the linked class for hours without success.

Can anyone either:

-Point me in the direction of a magic class that keeps aspect as well as unloading/destroying temporary images after resizing is complete, to keep RAM usage under control?

-Give me some (much needed!) guidance on where and how I could modify a class (such as the one posted) to destroy temporary images.

-Tell me if I'm going around this extremely wrong?

Oh, and I had the WideImage class working at one point, and it worked great, then suddenly stopped. I spent hours trying to fix it with no success.

My PHP install has GD, but not ImageMagick.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I managed to solve my own problem.

I sat down, wiped all my resize code, and started from scratch, and wrote this wonderful little function to do what I needed.

```
function resizeimage($targetw, $targeth, $input, $savedest) {
    list($oldw, $oldh) = getimagesize($input);
    $imgratio = ($oldw / $oldh);
     if ($imgratio>1) { 
         $new_width = $targetw; 
         $new_height = ($targeth / $imgratio); 
     } else { 
         $new_height = $targeth; 
         $new_width = ($targetw* $imgratio); 
     }
  $imagetemp = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
  $imageorig = imagecreatefromjpeg($input);
  imagecopyresampled($imagetemp, $imageorig, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $oldw, $oldh);
  imagejpeg($imagetemp, $savedest, 95);
  imagedestroy($imageorig);
  imagedestroy($imagetemp);
  unset($oldw,$oldh,$imgratio,$new_height, $new_width, $imagetemp, $imageorig);
}
```

Feed in target width and height, as well as the location of the input image (eg "uploads/images/testimage.jpg"), and where you want it saved ("uploads/images/resizedtestimage.jpg").

Hope this snippet helps someone in the future!

Answer (score 0):

Here is some GD image processing examples: 
http://fdcl.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/fdcl/trunk/modules/imageprocessing/gd/module.inc?revision=212&view=markup

One approach is this technique:

- Open image Scale to 500
- `imagedestroy($this->original_image)`
- Use image scaled to 500 and scale down to 150
- `imagedestroy($this->image500)`
- `imagedestroy($this->image150)`

The last idea is to use any available command-line tools to do the resizing for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar but used 2 apps that can be run from command line on a Linux server.

ImageMagick Mogrify: http://www.imagemagick.org/www/mogrify.html

```
mogrify -resize 750 "image.jpg"
```

will resize to 750 pixels wide

jpegoptim: http://freecode.com/projects/jpegoptim

```
jpegoptim "image.jpg" –max=70 --strip-all
```

will optimise jpeg to 70% and strip all unnecessary bloat from image.

Both run from CLI and offer a lot of command options, sure you could use either or both with not much difficult.

Comment: While these solutions look really good, my host is unfortunately not linux-based. It's purely webhosting with a PHP backend.

I'll keep these in mind for the future though